# How to change icon for a Marker (TMapMarkerDescriptor) in Delphi 10 for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi

Please can anyone explain me how to Change the Marker Icon in Delphi for a android App?

My try don't work

```
s.Create(16, 16); //Image size
position.Latitude := mapview1.Location.Latitude;
position.Longitude := mapview1.Location.Longitude;
MyMarker := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(Position, 'MyMarker');
MyMarker.Draggable := True;
Mymarker.Icon := imagelist1.Bitmap(s,0);
MyMarker.Visible :=True;
Fmarkers.Add(MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker));
```

Imagelist is a Timagelist on the form. added with a 16x16 image.

If i run my app, no marker is shown. do i comment // the line with the icon then all works fine but i have no custom marker icon.

i want a set of 4 different marker icons.

Comment: What is your variable `s` declared as?

Comment: s is TSizeF by my testing and researching about this problem. I can get custom icon by using TImage but not with imagelist, i continue my research

Answer (score 1):

`TSizeF.Create` returns an instance of the record, which you must save into your variable `s`. This should work (presuming you have a 16x16 bitmap at index 0 in your ImageList):

```
s := TSizeF.Create(16, 16);            //Image size
position.Latitude := mapview1.Location.Latitude;
position.Longitude := mapview1.Location.Longitude;
MyMarker := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(Position, 'MyMarker');
MyMarker.Draggable := True;
Mymarker.Icon := imagelist1.Bitmap(s, 0);
MyMarker.Visible :=True;
Fmarkers.Add(MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker));
```

You should also be able to just skip the creation into a different variable and use it directly from the constructor [untested] - `TSizeF` is a record, and therefore doesn't need to be destroyed:

```
MyMarker.Icon := ImageList1.Bitmap(TSizeF.Create(16, 16), 0);
```

Comment: This is a good tip. thank you.
**But it does not solve my Problem. The icon is still not displayed on the map** i think this is a map or marker problem

Comment: Do you have a 16x16 bitmap at the right location in the imagelist? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see if `Mymarker.Icon` is assigned after that line is executed? I can't do that for you, because I don't have your imagelist or the rest of your code. If this doesn't solve your problem, then edit your question and add more details. And **there's no reason to get upset at me**.

Comment: i am not upset to you :)
i have made a test with a Timage. i can assign the image to this. so the imagelist works great. 
do i need a special format or size of the image for the Marker Icon?

Comment: is there any other way to assign a icon to the marker?

Comment: I don't see anything in the source that says anything about the image size, and there is no other way to assign an icon according to that code. Have you checked the Google Maps documentation?

Comment: The Problem is you will find really few about tmapview android programming with Delphi. delphi is not the usual programming language for android.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the issue. The problem is that you need to find documentation about what the requirements are for the icon for a marker, and it's not Delphi or Embarcadero that provides that documentation. Once you find those requirements, we can help with how to write the Delphi code to meet them. If you really have issues with Delphi and Android, you can always use Java instead.

Comment: The problem is the TmapView and its TMapMarker. It is from Embarcadero implemented in Delphi and has nothing to do with the original google maps api. 
You can find this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/de/FMX.Maps.TMapMarkerDescriptor
here you find: icon = Tbitmap

Or this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/de/FMX.Maps.TMapView_Methods
for the  Tmapview Component

But nowhere is anything spezial to the Icon format.

i think i must go a complete other way to change the icon.
**Any Ideas?**

Comment: But it uses Google Maps, which means it must work with those guidelines. If Google has set limits on something, those limits apply.

Comment: There are no google limits on my Marker icon. i use the same icon in another Programm with TMS Gmaps for Win32 and have no problems.
The icon is 16x16 PNG. Nothing special. 
For the android version i have used the same icon and have tryed many others in different formats. I am sure this is a Delphi issue.

**Any ideas for other ways to apply a icon to the marker?**

Comment: Use **Marker.Remove** to eliminate the marker, and create a new in the same position with the new icon.

Answer (score -1):

Well i have been looking answer for the same thing now for long time and the only way i could change it was loading my png image to `TImage` component on Designer and then assign `Bitmap` from that. Like this:

```
MyMarker.Icon := Image1.Bitmap;
```

Also the size of the picture doesn't matter

Update: 
I found a way to put custom icon from imagelist

```
s.Create(16, 16); //Image size
position.Latitude := mapview1.Location.Latitude;
position.Longitude := mapview1.Location.Longitude;
MyMarker := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(Position, 'MyMarker');
MyMarker.Draggable := True;
MyMarker.Icon := ImageList1.Source.Items[0].MultiResBitmap.Items[0].Bitmap;
MyMarker.Visible :=True;
Fmarkers.Add(MapView1.AddMarker(MyMarker));
```